# Get first numbers from String

Tags: c#, regex, string

How to get the first numbers from a string?

Example: I have "1567438absdg345"

I only want to get "1567438" without "absdg345", I want it to be dynamic, get the first occurrence of Alphabet index and remove everything after it.

Comment: Did you try to do it by yourself?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the `TakeWhile` extension methods to get characters from the string as long as they are digits:

```
string input = "1567438absdg345";

string digits = new String(input.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: From what I can tell from the question the desired result in that case would be an empty string, and that is what it returns.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is upvoted this much as it does not do what is asked. 

This will only give you the first number when input starts with a number. When it starts with anything else you get an empty result.

Comment: @E.Hekkert: This was discussed eight years ago. I interpreted the question to expect an empty string as result if there wasn't a digit at the start of the string, and that is also the exact interpretation that almost everyone else answering the question made. The answer also clearly states what it does so that there is no confusion if you happen to interpret the question differently.

Comment: @E.Hekkert: If you want it to skip to the first digit, you can just use this: `string digits = new String(input.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());`

Comment: This doesn't work if the string starts with non digit characters.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti: That depends on what you expect in that situation. If there are no digits at the start of the string it returns an empty string. If you are looking for the first occurance of digits anywhere in the string, this doesn't solve that.

Answer (score 25):

The Linq approach:

```
string input = "1567438absdg345";
string output = new string(input.TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of this one. Beautiful!

Comment: How is this different than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 15):

Or the regex approach

```
String s = "1567438absdg345";
String result = Regex.Match(s, @"^\d+").ToString();
```

`^` matches the start of the string and `\d+` the following digits

Answer (score 7):

You can loop through the string and test if the current character is numeric via [`Char.isDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx).

```
string str = "1567438absdg345";
string result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) // loop over the complete input
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(str[i])) //check if the current char is digit
        result += str[i];
    else
        break; //Stop the loop after the first character
}
```

Answer (score 4):

forget the regex, create this as a helper function somewhere...

```
string input = "1567438absdg345";
string result = "";

foreach(char c in input)
{
   if(!Char.IsDigit(c))
   {
      break;
   }
   result += c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An old-fashioned Regular expressionist way:

```
public long ParseInt(string str)
{
    long val = 0;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([\d]+).*$");
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = reg.Match(str);
    if (match != null) long.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out val);
    return val;
}
```

If it cannot parse, the method returns 0.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach

```
private int GetFirstNum(string inp)
{
    string final = "0"; //if there's nothing, it'll return 0
    foreach (char c in inp) //loop the string
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()); //if it can convert
            final += c.ToString(); //add to final string
        }
        catch (FormatException) //if NaN
        {
            break; //break out of loop
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(final); //return the int
}
```

Test:

```
    Response.Write(GetFirstNum("1567438absdg345") + "<br/>");
    Response.Write(GetFirstNum("a1567438absdg345") + "<br/>");
```

Result:

1567438
0

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
string val = "1567438absdg345";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[1-9][0-9]*");

string valNum = reg.Match(val).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you get the first digit from the string.

```
string stringResult = "";
bool digitFound = false;
foreach (var res in stringToTest)
{
    if (digitFound && !Char.IsDigit(res))
        break;
    if (Char.IsDigit(res))
    {
        stringResult += res;
        digitFound = true;
    }
}

int? firstDigitInString = digitFound ? Convert.ToInt32(stringResult) : (int?)null;
```

Another alternative that should do it:

```
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

I dont know why I got an empty string as a result in the numbers list above though?

Solved it like below, but seems a like the regex should be improved to do it immediately.

```
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(firstResult, @"\D+").Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 10 years old but just incase someone else comes across it. The accepted answer will only give you the first number if the number is right at the start of the input string.

When your string starts with anything but a digit it will return a empty string.
You would first need to know the index of the first digit and do a substring before using the accepted answer.

```
string input = "abc123def456ghi";
string digits = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
    var indexFirstDigit = input.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
    if (indexFirstDigit >= 0)
    {
        digits = new String(input.Substring(indexFirstDigit).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Though using regex would require fewer lines

```
string input = "abc012def345ghi";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[\\d]+");

string digits = reg.Match(input).Value;
```