# C# Sort files by natural number ordering in the name?

Tags: c#

I have files in directory like that

```
0-0.jpeg
0-1.jpeg
0-5.jpeg
0-9.jpeg
0-10.jpeg
0-12.jpeg
```

....

when i loading files:

```
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
```

They getting in wrong order (they should go like above):

```
0-0.jpeg
0-1.jpeg
0-10.jpeg
0-12.jpeg
0-5.jpeg
0-9.jpeg
```

How to fix that?

I was trying to sort them but no way:

```
1) Array.Sort(files, (f1, f2) => f1.Name.CompareTo(f2.Name));

2) Array.Sort(files, (x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

Comment: may take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles

Comment: "Wrong order" according to who? `0-12.jpeg` comes before `0-5.jpeg` because `0-1` comes before `0-5`. The sorting method looks at characters, not number values.

Comment: Isn't the problem that file names are sorted as strings, not numerics.  Therefore, 12 always comes before 9. You could either make sure the file names are 0-09.jpeg or implement a comparer to convert the filename to a number and compare that.

Comment: @Mark Sherretta i guess you right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alphabetically, the "wrong" order is in fact correct. If you want it sorted numerically then you'll need to either:

1. convert the filenames to a list of numeric numbers and sort them
2. name the files in such a way that alphabetic and numeric sorting are the same (0-001.jpeg and 0-030.jpg)
3. rely on the file creation time to sort (presuming the files were created in order).

See the answer to [Sorting Directory.GetFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles) for an example of #3.

Comment: This link was helpful to me where I could perform numeric ordering by reading only numerical part of file name https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080636/1503372. This helped me to apply ordering without applying any changes to file naming rules.

Answer (score 31):

Time to get creative.

```
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(file =>
    Regex.Replace(file.Name, @"\d+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(4, '0'))
);
```

Using Regex replace in the `OrderBy Clause`:

`Regex.Replace(file.Name, @"\d+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(4, '0'))`

So what this does is it `pads` each match of numeric values in the file name with a `0` character to a `length of 4 characters`:

```
0-0.jpeg     ->   0000-0000.jpeg
0-1.jpeg     ->   0000-0001.jpeg
0-5.jpeg     ->   0000-0005.jpeg
0-9.jpeg     ->   0000-0009.jpeg
0-10.jpeg    ->   0000-0010.jpeg
0-12.jpeg    ->   0000-0012.jpeg
```

This **only** happens in the `OrderBy` clause, it does not alter the original file name.
You will end up with the order you are looking for.

If your file names have dates in them, it would still work:

```
pic_20230124_1528.jpg -> pic_00020000000200030000000100020004_0001000500020008.jpg
pic_20230124_1601.jpg -> pic_00020000000200030000000100020004_0001000600000001.jpg
pic_20230305_0951.jpg -> pic_00020000000200030000000300000005_0000000900050001.jpg
```

Comment: The simplest solution of all shown here. I bumped the padding up to 9 characters just in case.

Comment: Awesome solution! :-)

Comment: worth mentioning that this uses [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) and you need `using System.Linq;` in your script file ;)

Comment: @InteXX have in mind though that this will add some unnecessary overhead (I'm kinda sure you won't have like 1000000000 numbered files in most cases ^^) .. you should keep the padding as low as possible but as high as relevant in your specific use case ;)

Comment: I had to change this to `FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(n => Regex.Replace(n.Name, @"\d+", x => x.Value.PadLeft(4, '0'))).ToArray();` after running into various compilation errors, e.g. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>' to 'System.IO.FileInfo[]' (CS0029)` or `A local variable named 'n' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'n', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else (CS0136)`

Comment: This is amazing! I would mark this as useful a million times if I could!

Answer (score 7):

See the "CustomSort" function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052176/932418).

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { 
                    "0-5.jpeg",
                    "0-9.jpeg",
                    "0-0.jpeg",
                    "0-1.jpeg",
                    "0-10.jpeg",
                    "0-12.jpeg"};
list.CustomSort().ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Its output:

```
0-0.jpeg
0-1.jpeg
0-5.jpeg
0-9.jpeg
0-10.jpeg
0-12.jpeg
```

Answer (score 7):

For solving this problem you can use **StrCmpLogicalW** windows API.

For more details see [This Artice](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C).

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution. I first parsed the file path, then defined the order rules.

For the following code you need the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

```cs
Regex parseFileNameForNaturalSortingRegex = new Regex(
    @"
        ^
        (?<DirectoryName>.*)
        (?<FullFileName>
            (?<FileNameBasePart>[^/\\]*)
            (?<FileNameNumericPart>\d+)?
            (?>
            \.
            (?<FileNameExtension>[^./\\]+)
            )?
        )
        $
    ",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.RightToLeft
);

FileInfo[] filesOrdered = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\my\source\directory")
    .Select(fi =>
    {
        Match match = parseFileNameForNaturalSortingRegex.Match(fi.FullName);
        return new
        {
            FileInfo = fi,
            DirectoryName = match.Groups["DirectoryName"].Value,
            FullFileName = match.Groups["FullFileName"].Value,
            BasePart = match.Groups["FileNameBasePart"].Value,
            NumericPart = match.Groups["FileNameNumericPart"].Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups["FileNameNumericPart"].Value) : -1,
            HasFileNameExtension = match.Groups["FileNameExtension"].Success,
            FileNameExtension = match.Groups["FileNameExtension"].Value
        };
    })
    .OrderBy(r => r.DirectoryName)
    .ThenBy(r => r.BasePart)
    .ThenBy(r => r.NumericPart)
    .ThenBy(r => r.HasFileNameExtension)
    .ThenBy(r => r.FileNameExtension)
    .Select(r => r.FileInfo)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You filenames appear to be structured. If you just sort them, they sort as ordinary strings. You need to:

1. Parse the file name into its constituent component parts.
2. Convert the numeric segments to a numeric value.
3. Compare that structure in the desired order to get the intended collation sequence.

Personally, I'd create a class that represented the structure implicit in the filename. Perhaps it should wrap the `FileInfo`. The constructor for that class should parse the filename into its constituent parts and instantiate the properties of the class appropriately.

The class should implement `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>` (or you could create an implementation of [Comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx)).

Sort your objects and they should then come out in the collating sequence you desire.

If looks like your file names are composed of 3 parts:

- a high-order numeric value (let's call it 'hi'),
- a low-order numeric value (let's call it 'lo'),
- and an extension (let's call it 'ext')

So your class might look something like

```
public class MyFileInfoWrapper : IComparable<MyFileInfoWrapper>,IComparable
{
  public MyFileInfoWrapper( FileInfo fi )
  {
    // your implementation here
    throw new NotImplementedException() ;
  }

  public int    Hi         { get ; private set ; }
  public int    Lo         { get ; private set ; }
  public string Extension  { get ; private set ; }

  public FileInfo FileInfo { get ; private set ; }

  public int CompareTo( MyFileInfoWrapper other )
  {
    int cc ;
    if      ( other   == null     ) cc = -1 ;
    else if ( this.Hi <  other.Hi ) cc = -1 ;
    else if ( this.Hi >  other.Hi ) cc = +1 ;
    else if ( this.Lo <  other.Lo ) cc = -1 ;
    else if ( this.Lo >  other.Lo ) cc = +1 ;
    else                            cc = string.Compare( this.Extension , other.Extension , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ;
    return cc ;
  }

  public int CompareTo( object obj )
  {
    int cc ;
    if      ( obj == null              ) cc = -1 ;
    else if ( obj is MyFileInfoWrapper ) cc = CompareTo( (MyFileInfoWrapper) obj ) ;
    else throw new ArgumentException("'obj' is not a 'MyFileInfoWrapper' type.", "obj") ;
    return cc ;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement [Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netframework-2.0) method for your specific case and use it in `Array.Sort`.

```
private int CompareByNumericName(FileInfo firstFile, FileInfo secondFile)
{
    /* First remove '0-' and '.jpeg' from both filenames then... */

    int firstFileNumericName = Int32.Parse(firstFile.Name);
    int secondFileNumericName = Int32.Parse(secondFile.Name);

    return firstFileNumericName.CompareTo(secondFileNumericName);
}
```

```
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
Array.Sort<FileInfo>(files, CompareByNumericName);
```