# Reading file names, respectively?

Tags: c#

I have 1000 files in a folder, I want to find the name of the file, but when I do it
The file names are not sorted.

For example: These are my filenames

```
1-CustomerApp.txt
2-CustomerApp.txt
3-CustomerApp.txt
...
```

[image: screenshot]

```
var adddress = @"data\"; 
str = "";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(adddress);//Assuming Test is your Folder
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    str = str + ", " + file.Name;
}
```

Comment: They ARE sorted, but sorted as strings. When you have 1 2 10, they will be sorted as 1 10 2.

Comment: @Tony: if they *happen* to be sorted it's only because of a filesystem quirk (usually NTFS).  The same code run against the same set of files on an NFS or FAT partition will yield vastly different results.

Comment: Related question: [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Take a look at:
[this answer][1]...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077182/c-sharp-sort-files-by-natural-number-ordering-in-the-name

Comment: What is your question? How is finding a file related to sorting file names?

Comment: @Dan-o The point is that he wrote they are unsorted, but they ARE.

Comment: @Tony: No.  The point is that any observed similarity to any kind of sortedness [numerical or alphabetical] is purely happenstance, a coincidence, a side effect.  *The observation is incorrect!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use this to keep a "numerical" order

```
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.txt")
.OrderBy(m => m.Name.PadLeft(200, '0')).ToArray();
```

200 is quite arbitrary, of course.

This will add "as many 0 as needed" so that the file name + n 0 are a string with a length of 200.

to make it a little bit less arbitrary and "brittle", you could do

```
var f = d.GetFiles("*.txt");
var maxLength = f.Select(l => l.Name.Length).Max() + 1;
FileInfo[] files = f.OrderBy(m => m.Name.PadLeft(maxLength, '0')).ToArray();
```

**How does it work (bad explanation, someone could do better)  and why is it far from perfect** :

Ordering of characters in c# puts numeric characters before alpha characters.
So `0` (or `9`) will be before `a`.
But `10a`, will be before `2a` as `1` comes before `2`.

see char after char

`1` / `2` => `10a` first

But if we change 
`10a` and `2a`, with `PadLeft`, to
`010a` and `002a`, we see, character after character

`0` / `0` => equal

`1` / `0` => `002a` first

This "works" in your case, but really depends on your "file naming" logic.

**CAUTION : This solution won't work with other file naming logic**

For example, the numeric part is not at the start.

`f-2-a` and `f-10-a`

Because

`00-f-2-a` would still be before `0-f-10-a`

or the "non-numeric part" is not of the same length.

`1-abc` and  `2-z`

Because
`01-abc` will come after `0002-z`

Comment: That's if they want it in alphabetical order.  If they want numerical order they'll have to employ some string manipulation

Comment: @Dan-o This will give a "pseudo numerical" order.

Comment: @Dan-o In this case it leads to numerical order. But it's extremely brittle. It only works because the string after the number has the same length of all names.

Comment: I can't believe I've never thought of that.

Comment: @BrunoLM Oracle history X ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't really agree with the "extremely" brittle... The second version is probably better, indeed.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus can you elaborate on how does it work? why making them in the same length will cause the sort to be correct?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus It's not the hardcoded 200 that I consider brittle. It's that you assume that the part after the number has the same length. `1-abc.txt` will sort after `2-z.txt`. That's not a problem for the OP's dataset, but can quickly run into trouble on minor changes.

Comment: @CodesInChaos oh yes, and also f-10.txt would also be after f-2.txt if he had another "file naming structure"

Comment: @user844541 little explanation added

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus that is so cool!! :) super smart. but if you have the following string 2myfile.txt and 10myfil.txt (stupid example) then the padding will not add anything because both are the same length.

Comment: @user844541 yes, added some failing cases in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are sorted alphabetically. I don't know how do you see what they are not sorted (with what you compare or where have you seen different result), if you are using file manager, then perhaps it apply own sorting. In windows explorer result will be the same (try to sort by name column).

If you know template of how file name is created, then you can do a trick, to apply own sorting. In case of your example, extract number at start (until minus) and pad it with zeroes (until maximum possible number size), and then sort what you get.

Or you can pad with zeroes when files are created:

```
0001-CustomerApp.txt
0002-CustomerApp.txt
...
9999-CustomerApp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [alphanumeric-sorting](http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting) and sort the files' names according to it.

```
FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.txt");
files.OrderBy(file=>file.Name, new AlphanumComparatorFast())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you more or less what you want; it skips any characters until it hits a number, then includes all directly following numerical characters to get the number. That number is then used as a key for sorting. Somewhat messy perhaps, but should work (and be less brittle than some other options, since this searches explicitly for the first "whole" number within the filename):

```
var filename1 = "10-file.txt";
var filename2 = "2-file.txt";

var filenames = new []{filename1, filename2};

var sorted = 
    filenames.Select(fn => new { 
                                  nr = int.Parse(new string(
                                             fn.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsNumber(c))
                                               .TakeWhile(c => Char.IsNumber(c))
                                               .ToArray())), 
                                  name = fn
                                })
              .OrderBy(file => file.nr)
              .Select(file => file.name);
```