# How to sort PDF files in a directory in numerical order by its name in c#

Tags: .net, windows-8, c#

Here's what I have tried:

```
var vv = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Image").GetFileSystemInfos("*.bmp").OrderBy(fs=>int.Parse(fs.Name.Split('_')[1].Substring(0, fs.Name.Split('_')[1].Length - fs.Extension.Length)));
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the file names you are trying to sort?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077182/c-sharp-sort-files-by-natural-number-ordering-in-the-name

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you create a custom sorter class that implements the IComparer interface to sort the FileSystemInfo array.

Yeah, it's not as sexy as using LINQ, but it is clean

```
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Image");
        FileSystemInfo[] fi = di.GetFileSystemInfos("*.bmp");

        Array.Sort(fi, new SortByNum());

public class SortByNum : IComparer<FileSystemInfo>
{
    public int Compare( FileSystemInfo x, FileSystemInfo y)
    {
        // extract the numeric portion of the file name
        int val_x = int.Parse(x.Name.Split('_')[1].Substring(0, x.Name.Split('_')[1].Length - x.Extension.Length));
        int val_y = int.Parse(y.Name.Split('_')[1].Substring(0, y.Name.Split('_')[1].Length - y.Extension.Length));

        return val_x.CompareTo(val_y);
    }
}
```