# Invalid Error encountered while sending date in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, datetime

I have created a api where I am sending some json format data to third party. But there is one column name as `RFEDates` whose I am getting as

`"RFEDates":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"` .

So is there any way where I can convert that date into proper date format in `(dd-MM-yyyy)` format.

Below is my code.

```
public void CallMasterService(IPCOLO_BLOCKCHAIN_FIELDS ObjIp, out string Msg, out string ErrorMsg)
    {
        Msg = "";
        ErrorMsg = "";
        NEDataBlockChain Tobj = new NEDataBlockChain();
        NEDataBlockChain[] ObjArrayNEdata = new NEDataBlockChain[1];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.R4GSTATE))
        {
            Tobj.R4GState = "ABC";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.R4GState = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.R4GSTATE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.CMP))
        {
            Tobj.CMP = "CMPState";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.CMP = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.CMP);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.VENDOR_CODE))
        {
            Tobj.SAPVendorCode = "ABC1234";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.SAPVendorCode = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.VENDOR_CODE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.IP_COLO_SITEID))
        {
            Tobj.IPColoSiteId = "IN-123456";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.IPColoSiteId = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.IP_COLO_SITEID);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.SAP_ID))
        {
            Tobj.SAPId = "I-AB-ABCD-ENB-I111";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.SAPId = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.SAP_ID);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.INFRA_PROVIDER))
        {
            Tobj.InfraProvider = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.InfraProvider = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.INFRA_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.SITE_NAME))
        {
            Tobj.SiteName = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.SiteName = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.SITE_NAME);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.SITE_ADDRESS))
        {
            Tobj.SiteAddress = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.SiteAddress = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.SITE_NAME);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.TOWER_TYPE))
        {
            Tobj.TowerType = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.TowerType = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.TOWER_TYPE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.TOWER_TYPE))
        {
            Tobj.TowerType = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.TowerType = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.TOWER_TYPE);
        }

        string strRFCsDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.RFCDATE))
        {
            Tobj.RFCDates = strRFCsDate;
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.RFCDates = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.RFCDATE);
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE))
        {
            Tobj.ID_OD = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.ID_OD = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.DG_NONDG))
        {
            Tobj.DG_NonDG = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.DG_NonDG = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.DG_NONDG);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.EB_NONEB))
        {
            Tobj.Eb_NonEB = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.Eb_NonEB = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.EB_NONEB);
        }

        Tobj.status = "Active"; // site status

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.CITY_NAME))
        {
            Tobj.City_Name = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.City_Name = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.CITY_NAME);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.NEID))
        {
            Tobj.NEID = "INRJRJKRXXXXTW6001";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.NEID = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.NEID);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.FACILITY_LATITUDE))
        {
            Tobj.FacilityLATITUDE = "10.22";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.FacilityLATITUDE = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.FACILITY_LATITUDE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.FACILITY_LONGITUDE))
        {
            Tobj.FacilityLONGITUDE = "90.50";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.FacilityLONGITUDE = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.FACILITY_LONGITUDE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE))
        {
            Tobj.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE = "ENODEB";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.RJ_JC_NAME))
        {
            Tobj.RJ_JC_NAME = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.RJ_JC_NAME = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.RJ_JC_NAME);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.RJ_JC_CODE))
        {
            Tobj.RJ_JC_CODE = "12345";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.RJ_JC_CODE = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.RJ_JC_CODE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.COMPANY_CODE))
        {
            Tobj.CompanyCode = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.CompanyCode = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.COMPANY_CODE);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME))
        {
            Tobj.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME = "Test";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ObjIp.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE))
        {
            Tobj.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE = "1234";
        }
        else
        {
            Tobj.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE = Convert.ToString(ObjIp.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE);
        }


        //Web Api logic starts here

        ObjArrayNEdata[0] = Tobj;
        string apiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUrl"].ToString();

        var inputIPColoMaster = new
        {
            NEdata = ObjArrayNEdata,
        };

        string json = "";
        string inputJsonIPColoMaster = "";
        try
        {
            inputJsonIPColoMaster = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(inputIPColoMaster);
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJsonIPColoMaster);
            DataTable dtRes = new DataTable();
            string GISSendDate = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(json);
            dtRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);

            CommonDB ObjDB = new CommonDB();

            if (dtRes != null && dtRes.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MasterServiceResponse MSRobj = new MasterServiceResponse();

                GlobalVariables.WriteMessageInfoInLogFile("IPCOLOMaster : " + "SAPID: " + ObjIp.SAP_ID + " Response Code " + dtRes.Rows[0]["response-code"].ToString() + " Response Message" + dtRes.Rows[0]["response-message"].ToString());
            }

            if (dtRes != null && dtRes.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                CommonDB objDB = new CommonDB();
                ObjIp.BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG = Convert.ToString(dtRes.Rows[0]["response-message"]);
                ObjIp.BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE = Convert.ToString(dtRes.Rows[0]["response-code"]);

                CommonDB.UPDATE_BLOCK_CHAIN_INFO(ObjIp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            GlobalVariables.WriteMessageInfoInLogFile_Error("Error - Invalid  : " + inputJsonIPColoMaster + "Ex Message :" + ex.Message + " Service response "+ json);


            Msg = "1";
            ErrorMsg = ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to mean "Fri Jan 12 1968 20:06:43 GMT+0000"? Then it would be Unix Time in Millisecond format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime
    .ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(<<Your string or input>>);
string formatted = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: getting error as `String not recognized as valid Datetime`

Comment: CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateString = "-62135596800000";
string format = "ddMMyyyy";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);

Comment: Try that above one?

Comment: Is it negative value? "-62135596800000" ?

Comment: yes its negative value, and still getting the same error

Comment: DateTime myDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out myDate))
{
    // handle parse failure
}

Comment: Use above code block to capture exception. For sure that is not valid datatime. So when you get something which is not valid then try to capture that exception accordingly give some valid error.

Answer (score 0):

That integer is in microseconds since epoch time. I do not know of way to accept that `"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"` format, but you can create a new method (`GetIntegarFromApiResult` in my example) that pulls the integar value from the API result. Implementing that method is outside the scope of this question, but after that you can convert that to your required format like below:

```cs
int MicroSecsFromApiInput = GetIntegerFromApiResult(ObjIp.RFEDates);
long milliSecs = (long)MicroSecsFromApiInput / 1000;
DateTime date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(milliSecs).UtcDateTime;
string formatted = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: where is this coming from `GetIntegerFromApiResult` ?

Comment: That is a method that you can implement yourself. See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080636/14387852) as an example. However you might need to convert `"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"` to a string first.